# "Not allowed when Origin missing" Fontawesome error

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am new to Font awesome. I am trying to use font awesome icon chess icon in my HTML. The CDN I used is

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
```

The icons are not loading and I am getting following error in console i.e.

```
Not allowed when Origin missing
```

I expected the chess icons to load but it is coming as blank in my HTML.

Answer (score 4):

It's a known issue with using a `w3school.com` code snippet that's already addressed in GitHub issues within FontAwesome repo. In short, you need to start your own kit instead of using w3school's.

Official answer from FontAwesome team below:

> It looks like you were using a kit code from the w3schools.com web site. That kit code is intended to be used on w3schools.com and they a referrer check now on their kit. You can get your own free kit code here https://fontawesome.com/start. After getting our free kit code you can just replace the one from w3schools.com and everything should load just fine.

Full thread available [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/17622#issuecomment-777408205)

Answer (score -1):

Try using the latest CDN for awesome icon.